# HL7/FHIR, tracking a resource changes' author.

Tags: rest, hl7-fhir

Ok, so I'm working on some health related app. 
So far, we have our custom database, with Rest API end points, java spring app and oracle database.

Now they are considering to move to the HL7/FHIR specifications. I know pretty much nothing about this framework.

One of our requirements is some sort of audit module recording all sorts of events such as "this patient file got modified by that doctor".

The thing is the framework seems to include an AuditEvent module. 
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/auditevent.html

Ideally when a PUT rest call occurs on a "patient" resource, we would create and save a new AuditEvent resource.

The problem I face is how do I know the author of the PUT? The staff member that triggered the patient record update?

There is nothing in their REST recommendations that specifies how we are supposed to cover that aspect? The "author" of a PUT. 
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html#vread

Is it specific to how we implement the specifications, some sort of session/security related userID

Many Thanks

PS: there would be other types of events apart from just recording REST calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical mechanism for identifying users in FHIR is OAuth.  There's a bit of discussion on this in the specification here: http://www.hl7.org/fhir/security.html

It makes reference to the Smart on FHIR work which gives some additional guidance.

As well, you may want to look at the Heart work: http://openid.net/wg/heart

The high-level gist is that the authentication happens at the HTTP layer via redirects which then results in a token that gets included in the HTTP header for the PUT and other RESTful operations.

Comment: And also you should look at the Provenance resource, by which a client can provide a formal declaration of the client side information regarding the change